# Testing Goliath + Grape with Rspec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, ruby-grape, goliath

I'm trying to test a Goliath + Grape app like the following:

```
require 'em-synchrony/em-mongo'
require 'yajl/json_gem'
require 'goliath'
require 'grape'

class API < Grape::API
  version 'v1', :using => :path
  format :json

  resource 'categories' do
    # http://0.0.0.0:9000/v1/categories/
    get "/" do
      coll = env.mongo.collection('categories') #Connection Pool from Goliath ENV
      coll.find({})
    end
  end
end

class App < Goliath::API
  def response(env)
    API.call(env)
  end
end
```

these two classes are in a single file called app.rb. Running `ruby ./app.rb -sv` start a goliath app on `http://0.0.0.0:9000/v1/categories/` which is perfectly working, but needs rspec before making more complex endpoints. Anyway running the spec I get

> undefined local variable or method `app'

which I'm unable to get rid of:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/api_spec.rb
FFFF

Failures:

  1) App App GET /v1/categories get several categories of repositories by name
     Failure/Error: get "/v1/categories"
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `app' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x993eec4>
     # ./spec/api_spec.rb:9:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

the api_spec looks like the following:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe App do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  describe App do
    describe 'GET /v1/categories' do
      it 'get several categories of repositories by name' do
        get "/v1/categories"
        last_response.status.should == 200
        JSON.parse(last_response.body)["name"].should == "Ruby Web Frameworks"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

UPDATE :

adding app method to spec/api_spec.rb :

```
def app
    App
end
```

rise another kind of error :

```
  1) App App GET /v1/categories get several categories of repositories by name
     Failure/Error: get "/v1/categories"
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `call' for App:Class
     # ./spec/api_spec.rb:13:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

UPDATE

adding API class called from app method within spec/api_spec.rb :

```
def app
  API
end
```

get `undefined method`mongo'` :

```
Failures:

  1) App App GET /v1/categories get several categories of repositories by name
     Failure/Error: get "/v1/categories"
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `mongo' for #<Hash:0xad5ea58>
     # ./app.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <class:API>'
     # ./spec/api_spec.rb:13:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

see `coll = env.mongo.collection('categories')` inside API class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally have been able to make it working using [goliath test_helper](https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath/blob/master/lib/goliath/test_helper.rb). This is for tracking purpose, hoping it can help someone else.

In spec/spec_helper.rb add goliath test helper and all dependencies. In my case :

```
require 'em-synchrony/em-http'
require 'goliath/test_helper'
require 'yajl/json_gem'

Goliath.env = :test

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include Goliath::TestHelper, :example_group => {
    :file_path => /spec\//
  }
end
```

in spec/app_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../', 'app')

describe App do
  def config_file
    File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'app.rb'))
  end

  let(:api_options) { { :config => config_file } }

  it 'renders ' do
    with_api(App, api_options) do
      get_request(:path => '/v1/categories') do |c|
        resp = JSON.parse(c.response)
        categories = resp.map{|r|r['name']}
        categories.to_s.should =~ /Ruby Web Frameworks/
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Goliath application dir tree, looks like :

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/GGM$ ls -l 
total 48
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave  483 Feb 25 23:06 app.rb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave 6321 Feb 25 23:06 categories.json
drwxrwxr-x 2 lsoave lsoave 4096 Feb 25 23:06 config
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave  381 Feb 25 23:06 Gemfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave 2293 Feb 25 23:06 Gemfile.lock
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave   59 Feb 21 20:37 Procfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave  123 Feb 25 23:06 Rakefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave 7003 Feb 21 20:37 README.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave  238 Feb 25 23:06 README.mongoimport
drwxrwxr-x 2 lsoave lsoave 4096 Feb 25 23:23 spec
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/GGM$
```

where config and spec subdirs look like :

```
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/GGM$ ls -l config spec
config:
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave 870 Feb 25 23:06 app.rb

spec:
total 11
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave  777 Feb 25 23:06 app_spec.rb
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lsoave lsoave  218 Feb 25 23:06 spec_helper.rb
lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/GGM$
```

the main goliath app is the same as my first post :

```
require 'em-synchrony/em-mongo'
require 'yajl/json_gem'
require 'goliath'
require 'grape'

class API < Grape::API
  version 'v1', :using => :path
  format :json

  resource 'categories' do
    # http://0.0.0.0:9000/v1/categories/
    get "/" do
      coll = env.mongo.collection('categories') #Connection Pool from Goliath ENV
      coll.find({})
    end
  end
end

class App < Goliath::API
  def response(env)
    API.call(env)
  end
end
```

preatty simple in the end. If you want to go deeper have a look at https://github.com/lgs/GGM.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to provide a method in your test to specify the class of your app

```
def app
  App
end
```

Update

Try API class instead

```
def app
  API 
end
```

Comment: I don't know anything about goliath. But seems it should work if you use API class instead of App

Answer (score 0):

add other POST example:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe V1::API do
  it "login" do
    with_api V1::Login do


      post_request(path: "/v1/login", :head => {'authorization' => HTTP_BASIC_HEADER }, :body =>{mobile: 18600112233}) do |async|

        async.response_header.status.should == 201
        async.response.should == { mobile: '18600112233' }.to_json
      end
    end
  end

end
```